# Reshaper Respeller plugin: How to version control the dictionary and the added words

Tags: resharper

We are using Resharper with the [Respeller](https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2013/01/14/respeller-a-spell-checking-plugin-for-resharper/) plugin in Visual Studio 2015.
Is it possible to version control the user dictionaries? It is a waste for every developer in the team to add the words to their own dictionaries.

In the Resharper options, under Respeller I can see that the words that I added to the dictionary are shown like [this](https://gyazo.com/0da6a18e7e0ae43d1c34836abbd1f89d), but I cannot find the file in which these are stored.

Comment: I think you don't mean _"version control the user dictionaries"_. Instead you mean _syncing between developer machines_ (Even if the one often goes in hand with the other.)

Comment: I meant both things, "version control the user dictionaries" as in adding them to Git for example. But as you said, this goes hand in hand with "syncing between developer machines"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ReSpeller under R#2017.2/VS2017 even offers a setting for the dictionary path.

The default there is

```
C:\Users\%USER%\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Installations\ReSharperPlatformVs15_%HASH%\dic
```

Maybe it is in a similar location on your system.

Edit:
The words from the options dialog are saved in the global R# config file:

```
C:\Users\%USER%\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\Shared\vAny\GlobalSettingsStorage.DotSettings
```

You should be able to extract these using the configuration layers:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/2017.1/Sharing_Configuration_Options.html

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Indeed the dictionaries are there, but these dictionary files do not change when I add new words to them. The new words seem to be added in another file, but I cannot find that file. Check out this print screen, notice at the bottom the words that I added to the dictionary: https://gyazo.com/037b219864a01f52e2e8eb54b08dfef4

Comment: Ah, you are right. These words are saved in the global R# config file:
c:\Users\%USER%\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\Shared\vAny\GlobalSettingsStorage.DotSettings
You should be able to extract these using the configuration layers:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/2017.1/Sharing_Configuration_Options.html